# Using selenium and python, i want to find if the website has a specific string in and if it does print yes or if it doesnt print no

Tags: python, string, selenium, web, search

I am currently going onto a website and using the websites search bar to search a list of queries, the website then returns whether that query is availble or unavailable with a string. I want to be able to search the query and then check if the query is available or unavailable.

```
    try:
    nres = driver.find_elements_by_id(str("nres"))
    if nres ==
    print("Tag is unavailable")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Tag is available")
```

Comment: can you elaborate by providing an example of real website where you run code for search, what's the desired outcome and what's the actual outcome of your code?

Comment: @Fiuity Can you share the URL of the website on which you want to perform these tasks or provide the relevant HTML and also details about where you are getting stuck?

Comment: so the website is https://www.gamertagavailability.com/ and i basically want to be able to automate this whole process of filling in the search bar with gamertags from a list and then seeing if they’re available

Answer (score 1):

You can check it below, I've used the `explicitWait` to enter the value in the input and click on the button.

```
driver.get("https://www.gamertagavailability.com/")

gamerTags=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"mytag")))
gamerTags.send_keys("GameZoneOwner")

checkNowBtn =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"doitnow")))
checkNowBtn.click()

#I have taken the common XPath for the status as it's ID is different and verified for both the status.
status = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='test']/div//p[2]").text

if status == "seems to be available!":
   print("The tag is available ")
elif status == "is not available!":
   print("Tag is not available")
```

**import**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path")
driver.implicitly_wait(6)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.gamertagavailability.com/check.php")
driver.find_element_by_id("mytag").send_keys("Sampletext")
driver.find_element_by_id("doitnow").click()
time.sleep(2)
check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='nres']/p[2]").text
if check == "is not available!":
    print("Tag is not available")
else:
    print("Tag is available")
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```